# Как переслать сообщение из бота в группу и ответить на него с последующим переносом ответа в бота?

Tags: python, telebot

Я пишу бота для тех поддержки, мне нужно чтобы пользователь задавал вопрос в тех.поддержку и его вопрос перешел в группу (либо в личку, не обязательно), где служба поддержки будет отвечать на вопрос пользователя и после ответ службы поддержки перенесся обратно пользователю в бота.

Код:

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text == 'Поддержка')                              # Техподдержка
def support(message):
    support_all_user = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    button_appeal_user = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Обращение к тех поддержке', callback_data='button_appeal_user')
    support_all_user.add(button_appeal_user)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=f'''Для того, чтобы открыть ТЕХ ПОДДЕРЖКУ в боте:

Зайдите в "Профиль", "История заказов", выберете нужный, нажмите "Проблема с заказом". Заполните форму и ожидайте ответа модератора.
В поле с текстом детально описать ситуацию, предоставить фото ДО Вашей покупки и ПОСЛЕ!
Вам нужно заполнить поля и в теме указать номер заказа. Обязательно выбрать поле "Вопрос по заказу в боте". 
В поле с текстом детально описать ситуацию, предоставить фото ДО вашей оплаты и ПОСЛЕ, дождаться ответа модератора.

ВНИМАНИЕ!
ТЕХ ПОДДЕРЖКУ МОЖНО ОТКРЫТЬ НЕ ПОЗДНЕЕ 24 ЧАСОВ ПОСЛЕ ПОКУПКИ.''',reply_markup=support_all_user)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'button_appeal_user')           # Обращение к техподдержке
def appeal_tp(message):
    global help_user_id
    help_user_id = message.from_user.id
    tp_help = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)  # Покупка цемента
    create_new_appeal_user = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Создать новое обращение', callback_data='appeal1')
    list_of_references = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Список обращений', callback_data='appeal2')
    tp_info_user = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Информация', callback_data='appeal3')
    tp_help.add(create_new_appeal_user, list_of_references, tp_info_user)
    bot.send_message(message.message.chat.id, text=f'''Если у вас возникли проблемы с 
заказом или вы хотите связаться с 
командой магазина нажмите кнопку 
Создать новое обращение''', reply_markup=tp_help)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda message: message.data == 'appeal1')
def client_request_tp(message):
    message_tp = bot.send_message(message.message.chat.id, text='Введите ваще обращение к техподдержке:')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message_tp, forward)

def forward(message):
    # Пересылка сообщения в группу поддержки и сохранение информации о сообщеclearнии
    bot.forward_message(config.id_group, message.chat.id, message.message_id)
    #bot.send_message(message.message.chat.id, text=forwarded_message)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Дождитесь ответа поддержки, поддержка отвечает в течении 12 часов')


@bot.message_handler(commands=["answer"])
def process_start(message):
    support_file = open('C:/Programmirovanie/IDE/Microsoft VS Code/tp_help.txt', 'r')
    support_team = set()
    for line in support_file:
        support_team.append(line.strip())
    support_file.close()
    if str(message.chat.id) in support_team:
        need_help_user = []
        need_help_file = open('C:/Programmirovanie/IDE/Microsoft VS Code/tp_help.txt', 'r')
        for line in need_help_file:
            need_help_user.append(line.strip())

            need_help_file.close()
            for user in support_team:
                if message.chat.id > 0:
                    bot.forward_message(need_help_user[0], message.chat.id, message.message_id)
                else:
                    bot.forward_message(need_help_user[1], message.chat.id, message.message_id)

            bot.send_message(int(need_help_user[0]), 'Поддержка: ' + message.text, bot.get_me())

            with open('C:/Programmirovanie/IDE/Microsoft VS Code/tp_help.txt', 'r') as txt:
                lines = txt.readlines()
            with open('C:/Programmirovanie/IDE/Microsoft VS Code/tp_help.txt', 'w') as txt:
                for line in lines:
                    if line.strip('\n') != need_help_user and line.strip('\n') != need_help_user[1]:
                        txt.write(line)
```

Индекс **`0`** это айди администратора (не получается переслать). Индекс **`1`** это айди группы (получается отправить сообщение), но не знаю как на него ответить, помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Хотелось бы сказать, чтобы ты заменил индексы (0,1) на хотя бы enum (В идеале, создать класс со значениями данных списков)

Но перейдем к вопросу

По опыту создания HelpDesk систем в Telegram, я бы предложил 2 варианта реализации

Под заявками я буду обозначать "вопрос пользователя"

1. Создание системы принятия заявок

Сообщение пользователь отправляется в чат по типу *request.id* - *message.text*

Под этим сообщением Inline клавиатура с кнопкой "Принять". Когда данную заявку принимают, принявший человек, когда пишет сообщение в чат с ботом - оно отправляется пользователю

Считаю этот вариант самый лучший для подобной системы

Минимальные хранимые данные:

**ID заявки | TelegramID пользователя | MessageID сообщения, отправленного в общий чат или в ЛС | Тип отправленного сообщения (в общий чат/в лс) | TelegramID админа, с которым происходит диалог| статус заявки (ожидание, закрыта)**

Пример использования:

Создается заявка - заявка запоминается в БД - заявка отправляется в чат - заявку принимают - сообщение с заявкой изменяется - происходит закрытие заявки - запомненная ранее заявка изменяется в БД - сообщение с заявкой изменяется

2. Самый простой, но и самый плохой.

Каждая заявка имеет свой ID. Создаешь боту команду, например, /answer *ID* *Сообщение*. Данное сообщение пишется пользователю

Минимальные хранимые данные:

**ID заявки | TelegramID пользователя **

В-принципе, алгоритм работы с командами прост - написал команду - произошло действие

Comment: Тут больше вопрос как именно обработать сообщение пользователя в чате, что бы оно перешло пользователю в бота, пока до этого не дошел.

Comment: Получаешь из БД telegramID. bot.send_message(telegramId, message.text)

Comment: Это сделал. спасибо большое, но появилась новая проблема, у некоторых людей закрыта пересылка сообщений, как тут действовать?